# Spectral Clustering of Gaussian Mixture Model

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am working on Exercise 4.7.6(e) in R. Vershynin's *High-Dimensional Probability*. For convenience, I will put the background below:

> Let $m, n$ be a positive integers and, for $i = 1,..., m$, let $X_i = \theta_i \mu + g$, where $\theta$ is a symmetric Bernoulli random variable, $\mu\in\mathbb{R}^n$, and $g\sim \mathcal{N}(0, I_n)$. Let $\Sigma$ be the covariance matrix of $X$ and $\Sigma_m = (1/m)\sum_{i=1}^m X_iX_i^T$ be the empirical covariance matrix of $X$. Let $v$ be the eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue of $\Sigma_m$. Notice that $\mu$ is the eigenvector of $\Sigma$ corresponding to its largest eigenvalue (which equals $1 + \Vert \mu \Vert_2^2$).

The grouping of $X_i$ is based on the sign of $\langle v, X_i \rangle$, i.e., all $X_i$ with the same sign of $\langle v, X_i \rangle$ are classified to the same group. Now I want to show the following (Theorem 4.7.5 in Dr. Vershynin's notes):

> Suppose $\Vert\mu \Vert_2^2 \geqslant C\sqrt{\log (1/\epsilon)}$. Then, if $$
> m \geqslant \left(\frac{n}{\Vert\mu \Vert_2} \right)^c,
> $$
> where $c$ is an absolute constant, then, with probability no smaller than $1 - 4\exp(-n)$, the clustering strategy above will identify the communities correctly up to $\epsilon m$ misclassified points. *(Apart from this, I also want to find some bound on $c$, since it is an absolute constant)*

Here is what I have done so far:

> Now I have chosen some $0 < \delta \ll 1$ such that
> $$
> m = O(\delta^{-2} n) \implies \Vert \Sigma - \Sigma_m \Vert \leqslant \delta\Vert\Sigma \Vert
> $$
> Further, by Davis-Kahan I have shown that
> $$
> \sin\angle(v, \mu) \leqslant \frac{2\delta\Vert\Sigma \Vert}{\Vert\mu \Vert_2^2}
> $$
> Also, I have shown that grouping based on the sign of $\langle \mu, X_i \rangle$ will give a good prediction, and one needs to contrast this with prediction based on the sign of $\langle v, X_i \rangle$. Suppose WLOG that $\langle v, \mu \rangle > 0$. Then the groupings of $X_i$ based on these strategies will differ whenever $X_i$ lies in the small wedge $W$ enclosed by $v^{\perp}$ and $\mu^{\perp}$. Suppose $X_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, I)$. Then one has that
> $$
> Y_i = \left\langle\frac{v}{\Vert v \Vert_2}, X_i\right\rangle\sim \mathcal{N}\left(\frac{\mu^T v}{\Vert v \Vert_2}, 1\right),\quad
> \quad Z_i = \left\langle
> \frac{\mu}{\Vert \mu \Vert_2}, X_i\right\rangle \sim \mathcal{N}\left(
> \Vert\mu \Vert_2, 1
> \right).
> $$
> And the probability that the groupings of $X_i$ are different equals
> $$
> p = 2\mathbb{P}(\mu^T X_i < 0, v^T X_i > 0) = 2\mathbb{P}\left(
> Y_i < 0, Z_i > 0
> \right).
> $$
> But I am not sure how to proceed. It looks like $Y_i$ and $Z_i$ are not independent. Could anyone please give me a hint on how to bound this probability from above? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some hints for the problem:

1. As stated in the theorem, we should be choosing $m \geq \left( \frac{n}{\Vert \mu \Vert} \right)^c$ for some $c > 0$. If $c = 2$ (say), then using the theorem on covariance estimation (or more precisely, the high probability version for the tail bound Exercise 4.7.3), we should deduce that $\Vert \Sigma - \Sigma_m \Vert \lesssim \frac{\Vert \mu \Vert^3}{\sqrt{n}}$. (We can assume that $\Vert \mu \Vert \geq 1$, and also $n \geq \Vert \mu \Vert$ (why?).)
2. Let $v$ denote the unit eigenvector of $\Sigma_m$ corresponding to the largest eigenvalue. The Davis-Kahan theorem therefore implies that the distance between the unit eigenvectors, up to sign, satisfy $\Vert v - \eta \frac{\mu}{\Vert \mu \Vert} \Vert \lesssim \frac{\Vert \Sigma_m - \Sigma \Vert}{\delta}$, where $\eta \in \{\pm 1\}$, and $\delta = \Vert \mu \Vert^2$ is the spectral gap (why?). Assuming without loss of generality that $\eta = 1$, this means $\Vert \Vert \mu \Vert v - u \Vert \lesssim \frac{\Vert \mu \Vert}{\sqrt{n}}$ with high probability.
3. Now we should understand why the signs of $\langle \mu, X_i \rangle$ predict the communities of $X_i$ well. For each $i$, note that $\langle \mu, X_i \rangle = \theta_i \Vert \mu \Vert^2 + \langle \mu, g_i \rangle$. Thus, as long as $\langle \mu, g_i \rangle \lesssim \Vert \mu \Vert^2$, the sign will be correct. But since $\langle \mu, g_i \rangle \sim N(0, \Vert \mu \Vert^2)$, we can secure this fact with high probability. Using the assumption that $\Vert \mu \Vert \gtrsim \sqrt{\log(1/\epsilon)}$, this implies that the sign of $\langle \mu, X_i \rangle$ is correct with probability $O(\epsilon)$. By a Chernoff bound on this event for all $m$ points, this indeed holds for all except $O(\epsilon m)$ points with high probability.
4. To finish the argument, you want to argue that the signs of $\langle v, X_i \rangle$, which are equal to the signs of $\langle \Vert \mu \Vert v, X_i \rangle$, are also correct with high probability. This can be deduced by chaining the previous parts: with high probability, $\langle \mu, X_i \rangle$ is correct and is well separated from zero by a distance $O(\Vert \mu \Vert^2)$. But with high probability, $\langle \Vert \mu \Vert v, X_i \rangle \approx \langle \mu, X_i \rangle$, and they are separated by a distance $O(\Vert \mu \Vert^2)$. Choosing all the constants carefully means that for all $i$, the sign of $\langle \Vert \mu \Vert v, X_i \rangle$ is correct with probability at least $1 - \frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Applying the Chernoff bound argument to this implies that with high probability all but at most $\epsilon m$ of the points will have the wrong sign.

Answer (score 0):

Let us adopt the following notations

$\mu=r_1u_1, v=r_2u_2$ with $u_1$ and $u_2$ of norm $1,$ $\rho=\langle u_1,u_2\rangle,$ $Z_i=\langle u_i,g_i\rangle$ for $i=1,2$ where $g_i\sim N(0,I_n)$.
It is standard to see that
$(Z_1,Z_2)$ is Gaussian such that $Z_1,Z_2\sim N(0,1)$ and $E(Z_1Z_2)=\rho.$

The explicit calculation of your $p$ does not seem possible since it depends entirely from the distribution function $$F_{\rho}(z_1,z_2)=\Pr(Z_1<z_1,Z_2<z_2).$$

Your $X_i$ is $\theta_i r_1u_1+ g_i$ and you are interested in
$$\Pr(\langle X_i,u_1\rangle<0<\langle X_i,u_2\rangle)=\Pr(Z_1<-\theta_ir_1,\,  Z_2>-\theta_ir_1\rho)$$ which is easily expressed in terms of the number $F_{\rho}(-\theta_ir_1,-\theta_ir_1\rho).$ Even while using $Z_2=\rho Z_1+\sqrt{1-\rho^2}Z_3$ with $Z_1,Z_3$ independent and $N(0,1)$,  you land on $\Pr((Z_1,Z_3)\in C)$ where $C$ is a cone whose submit is not $(0,0)$, something not computable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yet is there any way to derive a nontrivial upper bound of this probability?

Answer (score 0):

$\DeclareMathOperator*{\PP}{\mathbb P}\DeclareMathOperator*{\E}{\mathbb E}\DeclareMathOperator*{\T}{\mathsf{T}}\DeclareMathOperator*{\sign}{\mathrm{sign}}$I think the other answers do not deal with the harder part of the problem. When $\lVert x \rVert_2 > \sqrt n$, the theorem about covariance estimation does not give any guarentee in fact, so in this case a different analysis should be used. I will post my answer in my homework below:

1. Note that $\E X = \E (\theta \mu) = \E g = 0$. $\Sigma = \E X X^{\T} = \E (\theta \mu + g) (\theta \mu + g)^{\T} = \E \theta^2 \mu \mu^{\T} + \E g g^{\T} = \mu \mu^{\T} + I_n$. The spectrum of $\Sigma$ is one eigenvalue $1 + \lVert \mu \rVert_2^2$ and $n-1$ eigenvalues $1$.
2. To use Theorem 4.7.1 (in fact, Exercise 4.7.3), we need to verify the condition. For any $x \in \mathbb R^n$, $\langle X, x \rangle = (\theta \mu^{\T} x + g^{\T} x)$. By the triangle inequality, $\lVert \langle X, x \rangle \rVert_{\psi_2} \preceq |\langle \mu, x \rangle| + \lVert x \rVert_2$. On the other hand, $\lVert \langle X, x \rangle \rVert_{L^2} = \sqrt{\E \langle X, x \rangle^2}=\sqrt{\langle \Sigma x, x \rangle} = \sqrt{\langle \mu, x\rangle^2 + \lVert x \rVert_2^2}\le \langle \mu, x\rangle + \lVert x \rVert_2$. Hence, we yield the bound with $K=O(1)$ as
   \begin{equation}
       \lVert \Sigma_m - \Sigma \rVert \le C\left(\sqrt{\frac{n}m} + \frac n m\right) \lVert \Sigma \rVert = C\left(\sqrt{\frac{n}m} + \frac n m\right) (1 + \lVert \mu \rVert_2^2)
     \end{equation}
   w.p. $1 - 2e^{-n}$ ($u = n$ is substituted.).
3. Plug $S = \Sigma$, $T = \Sigma_m$, $i=1$, and $\delta = \lVert \mu \rVert_2^2$ in the bound. Then,
   \begin{equation}
       \exists \theta \in \{-1,1\}: \lVert v_1(\Sigma) - \theta v_1(\Sigma_m) \rVert \le \frac{3\lVert \Sigma_m - \Sigma \rVert}{\lVert \mu \rVert_2^2}
     \end{equation}
   for the unit eigenvector $v_1$.
4. Calculate $\PP \{ \sign(\langle \mu, \theta \mu + g \rangle) = \theta\} = \PP \{ \langle \mu, \mu + g \rangle > 0\} = \PP \{ \langle \mu, g \rangle > \lVert \mu \rVert_2^2\} = \PP \{ N(0, \lVert \mu \rVert_2^2) > \lVert \mu \rVert_2^2\} \le 2\exp(-c \lVert \mu \rVert_2^2) \ll \varepsilon$.
5. Let $v' = v \lVert \mu \rVert_2$. We know by part (c) (WLOG set $\theta = 1$) that $\lVert v' - \mu \rVert_2 \le \frac{3\lVert \Sigma_m - \Sigma \rVert}{\lVert \mu \rVert_2}$.  We want to bound $\PP \{ \sign(\langle v, \mu + g \rangle) =  \sign(\langle v, \mu\rangle)\}$.

   If $m \succeq n / \varepsilon$, by part (b), $\lVert \Sigma_m - \Sigma \rVert \ll \lVert \mu \rVert_2^2$ w.p. $1 - 2e^{-n}$. Then, $\lVert v' - \mu \rVert_2 \le \lVert \mu \rVert_2 / 2$. In this case, $\lVert v, \mu \rVert \ge \lVert \mu \rVert_2^2 / 2$ and $\PP \{ \sign(\langle v, \mu + g \rangle) =  \sign(\langle v, \mu\rangle)\} \le \PP \{\langle v, g \rangle > \frac 1 2 \langle v, \mu \rangle\} \le \PP \{N(0, \lVert \mu \rVert_2^2) > \lVert \mu \rVert_2^2/4\} \ll \varepsilon$. By Chernoff's bound, the number of misclassified communities is bounded by $\varepsilon m$ w.p. $1 - e^{-\varepsilon m} \le 1 - e^{-n}$. By union bound, this finishes the proof.

   However, the bound wrote in the statements is $m \succeq (n / \lVert \mu \rVert_2)^c$, which can be smaller than $n$ when $\lVert \mu \rVert_2 \ge n^{1-1/c}$. We fix $c = 2$. In this case $\lVert \mu \rVert_2 \succeq \sqrt n$, we cannot expect Theorem 4.7.1 to give any guarentee. Hence, we use a new strategy. Observe that $X_i X_i^{\T} = \mu \mu^{\T} + \theta_i (\mu g_i^{\T} + g_i \mu^{\T}) + g_i g_i^{\T}$. When $\lVert \mu \rVert \gg \sqrt n$, the term $\mu \mu^{\T}$ dominates. Now formalize this.

   Write
   \begin{equation}
       \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m X_i X_i^{\T} = \mu \mu^{\T} + \mu \left(\frac 1 m \sum_{i=1}^m g_i\right)^{\T} + \left(\frac 1 m \sum_{i=1}^m g_i\right) \mu^{\T} + \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m g_i g_i^{\T}.
   \end{equation}

   Because $\frac 1 m \sum g_i \sim N(0, I_n / m)$, by concentration of norm, we have $\lVert \frac 1 m \sum g_i \rVert \preceq \sqrt{n/m}$ w.p. $1 - 2e^{-2n}$. Hence, the norm of two terms on the middle is bounded by $C \lVert \mu \rVert_2 \cdot \sqrt{n/m} $.

   We simply bound $\lVert \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^m g_i g_i^{\T}\rVert $ by Theorem 4.6.1 which gives $C(\sqrt n + \sqrt m)\preceq \sqrt n$ w.p. $1 - 2e^{-2n}$.

   Combining two bounds, we have $\lVert \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m X_i X_i^{\T} - \mu \mu^{\T} \rVert \preceq \sqrt n + \sqrt{n / m} \cdot \lVert \mu \rVert_2 \le \lVert \mu \rVert_2^2 / 2$. By Davis-Kahan, this implies $\lVert v - \mu \rVert_2 \preceq \lVert \mu \rVert_2^2 / 2$ and $|\langle v, u \rangle| \ge \frac 1 2 \lVert \mu \rVert_2$. Now $\PP \{ \sign(\langle v, \mu + g \rangle) = \sign(\langle v, \mu \rangle)\} \le 2\exp(-c\lVert \mu \rVert_2^2) \le 2\exp(-2n)$. By union bound of everything, there is no misprediction (i.e. $\varepsilon = 0$) w.p. $1 - 4\exp(-n)$.

In summary, if $\lVert \mu \rVert_2 \preceq \sqrt n$, we use the first analysis based on covarience estimation and otherwise we use the second analysis based on estimation of overlap with $\mu$. This proof gives a sharper bound: the algorithm works with $m \succeq \min(n / \varepsilon, (n / \lVert \mu \rVert_2)^2)$.